# Owl Slider Custom Control Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Unfortunately the controls that Owl Carousel render will not help me with my current project so I am trying to change a slide with a jQuery click event however I am having no luck.

I have been following the documentation on the [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) website.

This is the jQuery that I have managed to formulate:

```
   var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
   owl.owlCarousel();
   $('.car-hub-header-learn-more').click(function() {
       owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
   })
```

Here is my `a` tag html:

```
<a href="#" class="car-hub-header-learn-more"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Request Callback</a>
```

All carousel html as requested:

```
<div id="owl-new-car-main" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: -3px; opacity: 1; display: block;" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="owl-wrapper-outer"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 7612px; left: 0px; display: block; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1903px;"><div class="item">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>Scirocco</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row middle-xs">
        <div class="car-hub-header-image-box col-lg-12">
          <div class="row middle-lg center-lg">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <a href="#" class="car-hub-header-learn-more">Learn More <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <img src="/img/new-car-template/scirocco-transparent.png" alt="Scirocco GT">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <a href="#" class="car-hub-header-learn-more"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Request Callback</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="car-hub-header-info-container col-lg-12">
          <div class="row start-lg">
            <div class="col-lg-12 car-hub-header-info-box">
              <h2>FEATURED DEAL <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
              <span class="medium-underline"></span>
              <h3 class="car-hub-header-model-variant">GT Black Edition - 1.4 TSI Manual</h3>
              <div class="row center-lg car-hub-offer-container">
                <div class="col-lg-3 car-hub-header-offer-1">
                  <h2>£198 <span>Monthly</span></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 car-hub-header-offer-2">
                  <h2>£1500 <span>Deposit Contribution</span></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 car-hub-header-offer-3">
                  <h2>£198 <span>Customer Deposit</span></h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1903px;"><div class="item item-2">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div></div></div></div>

</div>
```

I was hoping that when I click my `a` tag that the carousel would go to the next slide however this is not the case, I get no errors in my console either.

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: try by adding `e.preventDefault()` inside click handler for `a` tag - `$('.car-hub-header-learn-more').click(function(e) { owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel'); e.preventDefault(); })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var $dots = $('.owl-dot');

function goToNextCarouselPage() {    
    var $next = $dots.filter('.active').next();

    if (!$next.length)
        $next = $dots.first();

    $next.trigger('click');
}

$('.car-hub-header-learn-more').click(function () {
    goToNextCarouselPage();
});
```